# Animate and remove a div - jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm removing a div from body with a fadeout effect with a delay.

```
$('#mydata div').each(function(i) {                 

        $(this).delay(200*i).fadeOut(1000);
            $(this).animate({
                "opacity" : "0",
            });

    });
    $('#mydata').remove();
```

But if i use $('#mydata').remove() animation doesn't work any solutions .. ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this :

```
$('#mydata div').each(function(i) {                 

        $(this).delay(200*i).fadeOut(1000);
            $(this).animate({
                "opacity" : "0",
                },{
                "complete" : function() {
                      $('#mydata').remove();
                }
            });

    });
```

Comment: use either daisy-chained method calling or function callback, you must

Answer (score 4):

You need to make the removal occur AFTER the animation completes. This can be added into the `animate()` call as the on complete parameter (a function which will be called when the animation finishes):

```
 $(this).animate({
         "opacity" : "0", //property
         1000, //duration of animation (optional)
         function(){$('#mydata').remove();} //function to run on complete (optional)
 });
```

You can read more in the [JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: you need to specify the duration after animation parameters. `}, 1000, function() {`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind still having the div in the DOM, you can [hide it](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), which is more simple:

```
$('#mydata').hide();
```

and you can specify speed and type of animation too

Answer (score 1):

You are removing the parent element before the children have faded out.

Try this:

```
$('#mydata div').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(200*i)
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .animate({
           "opacity" : "0",
        },
        function() {
            $(this).remove();
            if($("#mydata div").length == 0) {
                $("#mydata").remove();
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight mod on Bens answer works for me..

```
$( "#book" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=50",
    height: "toggle"
}, 5000, function() {
      // Animation complete.
});
```